# why to use indexeddb instead of cache api for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, angular-service-worker

I am using service worker and precache assets in install event.

I also have `fetch` listener which intercepts requests and caches then at runtime dynamically. I know that people say to use indexeddb for dynamic content such as json data and possibly images.

**Question:** Why isn't it a good practice to use cache API for that json data too even though it's request/response storage?

The reason I am asking this is because I tried the following: I have `index.html and main.js` as precached in `install` event and in `main.js` I have `axios` request which returns some json and puts it in `index.html`. If I use dynamic caching which means when the request to that json api endpoint gets made, it goes first to my service worker, which gets the response and puts it into `cache`. Then I tested that and when refreshed the page in offline mode, I still got the same result (json data put in index.html accordingly).

So I guess even though Cache API store request/response, it still worked for json endpoint api urls flawlessly.

Any good idea why to prefer indexeddb over cache API while using service worker?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to cache JSON data using the Cache Storage API, as an alternative to using IndexedDB. I would expect similar performance characteristics, and in both cases you could read/write the data from either the service worker or `window` context.

It would be slightly more awkward to use the Cache Storage API if you have JSON data that isn't already associated with a `Response` object, or that doesn't have a "real" request URL, since you'll have to effectively "fake" them. But that's not particularly hard to do:

```
const data = {
  // some data
};
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

const jsonResponse = new Response(jsonString, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
});
const cache = await caches.open('json-cache');
await cache.put('/some-json-url', jsonResponse);
```